latex listing renaming
I'm working on a project and on my paper I'm required to name the listings "Auflistung" but latex keeps naming them "Abbildung". I tried using the command \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Auflistung} but it's not working as it keeps naming the listing "Abbildung".
This is in my preamble:
usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}  
\usepackage[a4paper, 
margin=2.54cm, 
marginparwidth=2.0cm, 
footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000 
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true
    ]{biblatex}  

\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{
    \mkbibemph{#1}} 

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    breaklinks,
    hidelinks,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle,
    pdfpagemode = {UseOutlines},
    pdfpagelabels,
    ]{hyperref}            
    \urlstyle{rm}  
%\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Auflistung}

\lstset{
    language=Python, % Setzen Sie die Sprache
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, % Grundstil
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % Stil für Schlüsselwörter
    commentstyle=\color{gray}, % Stil für Kommentare
    stringstyle=\color{red}, % Stil für Strings
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}, % Stil für Zeilennummern
    stepnumber=1, % Jede Zeile nummerieren
    numbersep=0pt, % Abstand zwischen Nummern und Code
    showstringspaces=false, % Leerzeichen in Strings nicht anzeigen
    tabsize=4, % Tabulatorgröße
    breaklines=true, % Zeilen umbrechen
    breakatwhitespace=false, % Zeilenumbruch nur bei Leerzeichen
    numbers=left, % Zeilennummern links anzeigen
    firstnumber=1, % Erste Zeilennummer
    numberfirstline=true, % Nummeriert die erste Zeile
}

% 
\setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\newcommandx{\unsure}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\change}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!25,bordercolor=blue,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\info}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=OliveGreen,backgroundcolor=OliveGreen!25,bordercolor=OliveGreen,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\improvement}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=Plum,backgroundcolor=Plum!25,bordercolor=Plum,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\thiswillnotshow}[2][1=]{\todo[disable,#1]{#2}}

and this is a example of how I use the listing:
 \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        def prozess(env):  
            yield env.timeout(5)     
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Simples Beispiel wie das Timeout-Event in SimPy verwendet wird.}
    \label{fig:SimPyTimeout}
    \end{figure}

Minimal reproducible example would be this:
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    headings=small,
    parskip=half,           % Ersetzt manuelles Setzen von parskip/parindent.
    bibliography=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,       % Entfernt den letzten Punkt der Kapitelnummern.
    open=any,               % Kapitel kann auf jeder Seite beginnen.
%   final                   % Entfernt alle todonotes und den Entwurfstempel.
    ]{scrreprt}
% ===================================Praeambel==================================
\def\jobname{document}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}  
\usepackage[a4paper, 
margin=2.54cm, 
marginparwidth=2.0cm, 
footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000 
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true
    ]{biblatex}  

\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{
    \mkbibemph{#1}} 

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    breaklinks,
    hidelinks,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle,
    pdfpagemode = {UseOutlines},
    pdfpagelabels,
    ]{hyperref}            
    \urlstyle{rm}  
%\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Auflistung}

% Ändern des Namens der Bibliographie
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  Bibliography = {Literaturverzeichnis},
}




\lstset{
    language=Python, % Setzen Sie die Sprache
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, % Grundstil
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % Stil für Schlüsselwörter
    commentstyle=\color{gray}, % Stil für Kommentare
    stringstyle=\color{red}, % Stil für Strings
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}, % Stil für Zeilennummern
    stepnumber=1, % Jede Zeile nummerieren
    numbersep=0pt, % Abstand zwischen Nummern und Code
    showstringspaces=false, % Leerzeichen in Strings nicht anzeigen
    tabsize=4, % Tabulatorgröße
    breaklines=true, % Zeilen umbrechen
    breakatwhitespace=false, % Zeilenumbruch nur bei Leerzeichen
    numbers=left, % Zeilennummern links anzeigen
    firstnumber=1, % Erste Zeilennummer
    numberfirstline=true, % Nummeriert die erste Zeile
}

% 
\setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\newcommandx{\unsure}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\change}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!25,bordercolor=blue,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\info}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=OliveGreen,backgroundcolor=OliveGreen!25,bordercolor=OliveGreen,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\improvement}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=Plum,backgroundcolor=Plum!25,bordercolor=Plum,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\thiswillnotshow}[2][1=]{\todo[disable,#1]{#2}}
%
% ===================================Dokument===================================
\title{test title}
\author{author}
\begin{document}
something something text
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        def prozess(env):  
            yield env.timeout(5)     
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Simples Beispiel wie das Timeout-Event in SimPy verwendet wird.}
    \label{fig:SimPyTimeout}
    \end{figure}
something something text
\begin{raggedright}
    \printbibliography
    \label{sec:literaturverzeichnis}
\end{raggedright}
\end{document}

i added some logs i found regarding listings but if i delete scrhack
it dosen change anything
ackage scrhack Warning: unknown \lstlistoflistings definition found!
(scrhack)                Maybe you are using a unsupported listings version.

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd) (./Bachelorarbeit.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ngerman.lbx (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx)) (./Bachelorarbeit.bbl) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (./Bachelorarbeit.out) (./Bachelorarbeit.out) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-pdftex.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ptm.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ztmcm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlztmcm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsztmcm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxztmcm.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}

I really have no idea what to do so any help would be appreciated
I used \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Auflistung} but that dosen't work

Please add a compilable [mre] to your question.

i did add a minimal reproducible codeblock if that was what you ment?

i added some logs that might have to do something with that

Don't wrap your listing in a figure environment and use the caption= option of lstlisting instead:
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Auflistung}

\lstset{
    language=Python, % Setzen Sie die Sprache
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, % Grundstil
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % Stil für Schlüsselwörter
    commentstyle=\color{gray}, % Stil für Kommentare
    stringstyle=\color{red}, % Stil für Strings
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}, % Stil für Zeilennummern
    stepnumber=1, % Jede Zeile nummerieren
    numbersep=0pt, % Abstand zwischen Nummern und Code
    showstringspaces=false, % Leerzeichen in Strings nicht anzeigen
    tabsize=4, % Tabulatorgröße
    breaklines=true, % Zeilen umbrechen
    breakatwhitespace=false, % Zeilenumbruch nur bei Leerzeichen
    numbers=left, % Zeilennummern links anzeigen
    firstnumber=1, % Erste Zeilennummer
    numberfirstline=true, % Nummeriert die erste Zeile
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}
something something text
\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={Simples Beispiel wie das Timeout-Event in SimPy verwendet wird.},
  label=fig:SimPyTimeout
]
def prozess(env):  
    yield env.timeout(5)     
\end{lstlisting}
something something text
\end{document}



oh alright cool, that works for me, thank you very much :D

@benb You're welcome!
